# Display a timestamp of when a cell in a range was selected

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I want, when a certain cell is selected that displays "Yes," another cell automatically displays the timestamp of when that cell was selected as Yes.

I am having issues continuing the loop on the next row.
I want once the If/Then statement has finished, the For loop sends the code to the next sequential line.

Screen print of the worksheet:
[image]

```vb
Sub timestampdu()

Dim tcell As Range
Dim trcell As Range
Dim j As Integer

Set tcell = Range("F6:F100")
Set trcell = Range("C6:C100")

For j = 1 To 100
    If Range("F6").Value = "Yes" Then
        Cells(6, 3).Value = Now
        trcell.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    End If
Next j

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one version

```
Sub Date_Yes()
Dim rng As Range, c As Range, sh As Worksheet


Set sh = ActiveSheet

With sh
Set rng = .Range("F2:F" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
For Each c In rng.Cells
If c = "Yes" Then .Range("C" & c.Row).Value = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yy")
Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I there a way for this macro to automatically run when the "Yes" value is entered on a row in column F without changing the dates on other rows. I.e., I would want this program to track when a specific cell is changed to "Yes" and have different timestamps for different entries of "Yes"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Selection_Change event of the Sheet. For this place this code into the sheet's code module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F:F")) Is Nothing Then
  If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
    Cells(Target.Row, "C") = Now()
    Cells(Target.Row, "C").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
  End If
End If
End Sub
```

Remarks: Every time you select a cell with "Yes" content the actual date will overwrite the cell previous content.
I not suggest to go through all the cells every time a "Taken" cell is selected, since in this case all the previous dates will be overwritten.